# KMeans init own centroids

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I want to init KMeans with centroids that were earlier calculated. Here are my centroids:

```
[[   0.6015258     8.17956199    0.12919147    3.59169105    1.64488952
     1.24190854]
 [  12.84438984  181.76167076    0.22235872  456.31326781    5.97379197
    39.55610156]
 [   5.25691959  105.38839179    0.24659986   69.29062276    7.92543546
    10.66935099]
 [  22.04545455  708.99242424    0.29040404  926.11616162   15.83585859
    45.92929293]
 [  23.45454545 1801.37878788    0.28787879  615.8030303    20.71212121
    39.96969697]]
```

My KMeans initialization:

```
clustering_kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5, init=centroids).fit(data)
centers = clustering_kmeans.cluster_centers_
print(centers)
```

And I received this:

```
[[   1.52026287   20.61007667    2.63745893    9.59474261    8.93975904   6.06900329]
 [  15.5         117.41666667    4.25        393.41666667   15.16666667   152.25      ]
 [   7.86885246  215.83606557    9.18032787   62.95081967   50.13114754   27.73770492]
 [  31.2         160.2           6.         1031.2          18.2           325.8       ]
 [  59.         1419.           11.         1838.           81.           369.        ]]
```

Shouldn't centers be the same?

Comment: Depends on how accurate your centroids are. If they aren't accurate enough, `KMeans.fit` will adjust them appropriately.

Comment: Why your *initial* centroids should be the same with the *final* ones?

Comment: Just curious, if you initialize `KMeans` with the _new_ `cluster_centers_`, do the centers change again?